# discord.js edit embed timeout

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a fun command and I got no errors so far.

Here's the code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {
    name: "spin",
    description: "spin",
    permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],

    run: async (client, message, args) => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
  
  let number = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"];

  let secondEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("The wheel is spinning...")
  .setColor('#fc8eac')
  .setTimestamp()
  .addField("Spinner", `<@!${message.author.id}>`, true)
  .addField("Result", `  <a:dotload:928216650614968321>`, true)
  .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/928270805492699177.webp?size=160&quality=lossless')
  .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL());

    const m = await message.channel.send({embeds: [secondEmbed] })
    
  let firstEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("The wheel has stopped spinning!")
  .setColor('#fc8eac')
  .setTimestamp()
  .addField("Spinner", `<@!${message.author.id}>`, true)
  .addField("Result", `${number[Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length)]}`, true)
  .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/928270805492699177.webp?size=160&quality=lossless')
  .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL());

  await m.edit(({embeds: [firstEmbed] }), {timeout: 5000})
}
}
```

I'm having trouble on this line 'coz the embed gets edited in less than the given time length {timeout: 5000}

```js
await m.edit(({embeds: [firstEmbed] }), {timeout: 5000})
```

I need help on how to fix this.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a `timeout` option for the [`Message#edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) method. At least I can't find it in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageEditOptions).

However, you could use the good old [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) method to achieve the same:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  m.edit({ embeds: [firstEmbed] })
}, 5000)
```